# Sampling and DTFT in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to produce a signal x=-2*cos(100*pi*n)+2*cos(140*pi*n)+cos(200*pi*n)
So I put it like this :

```
N=1024;
for n=1:N
    x=-2*cos(100*pi*n)+2*cos(140*pi*n)+cos(200*pi*n);
end
```

But What I get is that the result keeps giving out 1
I tried to test each values according to each n, and I get the same results for any n
For example -2*cos(100*pi*n) with n=1 has to be -1.393310473. Instead of that, Matlab gave the result -2 for it and it always gave -2 for any n
I don't know how to fix it, so I hope someone could help me out! Thank you!

Comment: How did you obtain the result -1.393310473?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you get the idea that `-2*cos(100*pi)` should be anything other than `-2`. Maybe you are not aware that Matlab works in radians?

Look at your expression. Each term can be factored to contain `2*pi*(an integer)`. And you should know that `cos(2*pi*(an integer))` = 1.

So the results are exactly as expected.

What you are seeing is basically what happens when you under-sample a waveform. You may know that the Nyquist criterion says that you need to have a sampling rate that is at least two times greater than the highest frequency component present; but in your case, you are sampling one point every 50, 70, 100 complete cycles. So you are "far beyond Nyquist". And that can only be solved by sampling more closely.

For example, you could do:

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 1024); % sample the waveform 1024 times between 0 and 1
f1 = 50;
f2 = 70;
f3 = 100;
signal = -2*cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 2*cos(2*pi*f2*t) + cos(2*pi*f3*t);

figure; plot(t, signal)
```

Comment: I see, so can you suggest some ideals for me to create an signal of x(n) =-2*cos(100*pi*n)+2*cos(140*pi*n)+cos(200*pi*n)!? Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain what you want the result to be? If you insist that `n` is an integer, there is nothing I can do for you. But if you recognize that a "signal" typically has a time component, then you should be able to see that the code snippet I gave above is exactly what I _think_ you need. If that's not it, you need to explain more clearly what you want and why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using degrees when you are doing your calculations, so do this:

```
n = 1:1024
x=-2*cosd(100*pi*n)+2*cosd(140*pi*n)+cosd(200*pi*n);
```

`cosd` uses degrees instead of radians. Radians is the default for `cos` so matlab has a separate function when degree input is used. For me this gave:

```
-2*cosd(100*pi*1) = -1.3933
```

The first term that I got using:

```
x=-2*cosd(100*pi*1)+2*cosd(140*pi*1)+cosd(200*pi*1)
x = -1.0693
```

Also notice that I defined n as n = 1:1024; this will give all integers from 1,2,...,1024, 
there is no need to use a for loop since many of Matlab's built in functions are vectorized. Meaning you can just input a vector and it will calculate the function for every element in the vector.